# how to increment CSS ID using PHP programmatically

Tags: php, css

how can i increment my css ID using php programmatically?

```
foreach ($query_cat->result() as $row_cat)
{
    $row_cat_id = $row_cat->id;

    echo '<div class="product-wrapper">';
    echo '<div id="product-header" class="product-header">';
    echo $row_cat->title;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    $query_prod = $this->db->get_where('products', array('category_id'=>$row_cat_id));

    foreach ($query_prod->result() as $row_prod)
    {
        $row_prod_id = $row_prod->id;
        echo '<div id="product-contents" class="product-contents">';
        echo $row_prod->title.'&nbsp;'.$row_prod->id;
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

what i want to happen is to increment the id **product-header** and **product-contents** depending on the numbers of rows generated

something like this

product-header1, product-header2, product-header3....
product-contents1, product-contents2, product-contents3....

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialise an incremental variable before the `foreach`.

```
$i = $j = 0;
foreach ($query_cat->result() as $row_cat) {
    $i++;
    $row_cat_id = $row_cat->id;
    echo '<div class="product-wrapper">';
    echo '<div id="product-header'.$i.'" class="product-header">';
    ...

    foreach ($query_prod->result() as $row_prod) {
        $j++;
        $row_prod_id = $row_prod->id;
        echo '<div id="product-contents'.$j.'" class="product-contents">';
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: By resetting `$j` before each iteration of the inner loop you'll produce non-unique ids...

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = $j = 1;
foreach (...) {
    printf('<div id="product-header-%u" class="product-header">', $i++);

    foreach (...) {
        printf('<div id="product-contents-%u" class="product-contents">', $j++);
    }
}
```